# Mysql database queries not showing in command line when importing using command line phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Friend i am trying to import sql database using command line it is importing fine with this command but not showing progress in command line

```
C:\xampp\mysql\bin

mysql  -u username -p databasename < dump.sql
```

Comment: Also see [mysql fast imports from dump](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster)

Answer (score 0):

Its normal for there not to be any output when importing data in this way using `mysql`.

You'll get a prompt back when it finishes.

Comment: Yesterday i imported it . it was showing queries also . but forgot the command.

Comment: if you run 'show processlist' in a separate mysql instance you can see queries being run.